# How to match every A's and B's but not a certain substring

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to match every single A and B but not a certain combination of it.
like it would match aabaaa but not abba.
So in other words it would match any combination of it except abba. so far my code looks like this

```
\b(ab|b+&a+|a+|b+&a+&b{1}|a{0}&b+)+
```

Comment: I don't understand your regex. What language/tool are you using for this?

Comment: Please describe how you got to that regex. Especially explain what `&` means, and what sense `{0}`/`{1}` make.

Comment: Does your regex flavour support negative lookaheads?

Comment: @toddlermenot it should be `if (!string.equals("abba"))`

Comment: You need to let us know what flavor of regex you're using. Some ones like Javascript don't support common features like look-behinds.

Comment: Sorry i should point out i'm using scala. Yes it does support positive and negative lookaheads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should using negative lookahead:

```
^(?!abba$)[ab]+$
```

i.e match any combination of `a` and `b` except `abba`.

Comment: Don't forget the case insensitive mode modifier!!